# Launching Minecraft from the command line

Tags: shell, minecraft

I am trying to launch Minecraft from the command line when I simply input `java -jar <minecraft file location>` it turns up with the error `Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Main` I know that this question has been asked before periodically but the most recent response is several years old and no longer works. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming.  A better place to post  your question would be on a minecraft forum, but I would try running from within the directory where the JAR resides to starat with if you aren't already.

Comment: Minecraft requires certain arguments to work. Take a look at the `version.json` inside of the `.minecraft/versions/` folder to see what arguments it expects.

Answer (score -1):

Launching is not esay. It is a lot of work. The command is long and different for each Version. But [there is a program](https://pypi.org/project/minecraft-launcher-cmd/) which does all the work for you.